# Rectifying vs ohmic behavior?

Tags: physics, solid-state-devices

I'm (still!) studying Solid State Electronics on Müller, Kamins and Chan's textbook "Device Electronics for Integrated Circuits" and in chap.4's summary about *Metal-semiconductor contacts* I've come across this statement:

> [The Schottky theory] predicts blocking contacts and rectifying
>   behavior for n-type semiconductors if the metal work function \$\Phi_M\$
>   exceeds the semiconductor work function \$\Phi_S\$ and ohmic behaviour if
>   \$\Phi_S\$ is greater than \$\Phi_M\$. The inverse is true for metal contacts
>   to *p*-type semiconductors

What's the difference between *rectifying behavior* and *ohmic behaviour*? I just need to get a gist of it, no need of big and complicated formulæ...

Answer (score 3):

A [Ohmic contact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohmic_contact) is a junction between two (semi)conductors that obeys Ohm's law, i.e. its current is proportional to the applied voltage.

A rectifying contact instead creates a [rectifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier), i.e. a two terminal component where current is not proportional to applied voltage. In a rectifier current can be any value if applied voltage is above zero, and current is zero if applied voltage is less than zero, as in this image:

[image]
(thanks to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_modelling#Mathematically_idealized_diode))

Comment: therefore an ideal diode shows a rectifying behaviour, did I understand correctly?